# Not exist and minus

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

Can anyone tell me diffrence between NOT EXIST and MINUS operator in SQL ? And When can i use ?and which one gives better performance?

Comment: One is a set-based operator similar to `union` and the other is a boolean expression similar to `in`.  Your question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 5):

You use `MINUS` only when it's about the same column(s). This can lead to very readable queries:

```
select dept_id from employees where salary > 1000
minus
select dept_id from employees where salary < 500;
```

`NOT EXISTS` is much more flexible, but for a query that can easily be expressed with `MINUS` the query may get less readable:

```
select dept_id from departments d
where exists
          (select * from employees e where e.dept_id = d.dept_id and e.salary > 1000)
and not exists 
          (select * from employees e where e.dept_id = d.dept_id and e.salary < 500);
```

As to speed there should be not much of a difference. Don't worry about that. Write your queries as readable as possible and only consider re-writing them when running into performance issues. (But these are usually more about appropriate indexes and not so often about how the query is written. Oracle is good at understanding queries, and it might even re-write a `MINUS` query to a `NOT EXISTS` query or vice versa internally before executing it.)